# A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types edm.string and edm.guid for kind equal

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, breeze, breeze-sharp

I implementing a filter using breeze predicate. Using BreezeJs and ASP.NET WebAPI(Breeze Server Side) with Entity Framework

The predicate looks like this:

```html
var predicate = breezeProvider.breeze.Predicate.create('serialNumber', '==', $scope.filter.serialNumber);
predicates.push(predicate);
```

When I execute the query. Breeze throw an exception with the following messages:

> A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types edm.string and edm.guid for kind equal

The $scope.filter.serialNumber is a string and serialNumber is a GUID property

The url is as follow.

> http://localhost:51969/breeze/WarehouseProductTransactions/GetProducts?$filter=(StatusId ne 3d) and (WarehouseId eq 1d) and (AuthorizedADUserId eq 'bTdbnW8t6Uu4D4KHCoQOhg==') and (SerialNumber eq guid'1b9d065e-eb48-4f3d-883c-2c841771a3e8')&$orderby=Id&$top=5&$expand=Inventory,AuthorizedADUser&$inlinecount=allpages&)

Note the snippet:

> (SerialNumber eq guid'1b9d065e-eb48-4f3d-883c-2c841771a3e8')

My server side is as follow:

```
[EnableBreezeQuery(MaxNodeCount = 200)]
public IQueryable<WarehouseProductTransactionDetail> GetProducts()
{
    return _contextProvider.Context.WarehouseProductTransactionDetails;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can resolve this situation but no idea.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is it possible that the serialNumber coming from the client is being understood as a string and then the server-side code is attempting to compare with a GUID. I don't know much about these specific technologies but I'd guess the server needs to convert the value from the client to a GUID before comparing. Or the value from the server to a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue when comparing userId in Breeze query. Breeze appends 'guid' in the OData query.

I was able to fix this issue by appending `.toType("entityTypeName")` to the breeze query.

```
let query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from('orders');          
let predicate = breeze.Predicate.create("CreatedBy", "==", userId);


query = query.where(predicate).toType("Order");
```